# Out of order executions

Tags: ios, swift, execution, timing

I have one method, "firstMethod" that calls 4 methods, each of which return an int. At the end of firstMethod I want it to print the sum of the ints of the returns of the methods it called. So like this

```
firstMethod()
{
   var sumOfMinutes = 0 //line A
   sumOfMinutes = sumOfMinutes + secondMethod() //Line B
   sumOfMinutes = sumOfMinutes + thirdMethod() //Line C
   sumOfMinutes = sumOfMinutes + fourthMethod() //Line D
   sumOfMinutes = sumOfMinutes + fifthMethod() //Line E
   print(sumOfMinutes) //line F
}

secondMethod() -> Int
{
   var number = generateRandom()
   print(number)
   return number
}

thirdMethod() -> Int
{
   var number = generateRandom()
   print(number)
   return number
}

fourthMethod() -> Int
{
   var number = generateRandom()
   print(number)
   return number
}

fifthMethod() -> Int
{
   var number = generateRandom()
   print(number)
   return number
}

generateRandom() -> Int
{
   //this method gets a random number out of an array
}
```

But what this keeps printing is not what is expected. An example of what it prints is:

0
5
2
9
4

**It seems that it is executing Line A, then line F, then lines B C D and E. Why would this be happening? It isnt making any sense to me **

Comment: Show the actual implementation of the `generateRandom` method.

Comment: Return arc4random_uniform(9) + 1

Comment: The code in your question states you get a random number out of an array. Please update your question with your real code copy and pasted into place.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if the methods also print some info which method they are.

Comment: Also, given the code you have shown, line F would be a sum of all the other numbers, which would **not** be the "5" in "0 5 2 9 4". The way you have presented the question doesn't seem to support the effect you are seeing.

Comment: The sum of the numbers is what I want line F to be. I am not really sure what you are trying to say about the "5", except that it is just an example of a random number that was generated in thirdMethod. I will come up with a better way to represent what I have, because it is more complicated than what I have. Ill make an edit to the above when I have time. Thanks!